# libmpdec mpd_qncopy memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers

https://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/doc/libmpdec/assign-convert.html

```
mpd_t *mpd_qncopy(const mpd_t *a);
```

> Returns a pointer to a fresh copy of a, NULL on failure.

What does **"a fresh copy"** mean? 
Where does it **allocate** the **new pointer** without any `mpd_context_t` given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fresh copy" means allocate memory and copy the decimal object over. The [full implementation](https://github.com/wittgena/mpdecimal/blob/master/libmpdec/mpdecimal.c#L1956) is:

```
mpd_t *
mpd_qncopy(const mpd_t *a)
{
    mpd_t *result;

    if ((result = mpd_qnew_size(a->len)) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    memcpy(result->data, a->data, a->len * (sizeof *result->data));
    mpd_copy_flags(result, a);
    result->exp = a->exp;
    result->digits = a->digits;
    result->len = a->len;

    return result;
}
```

It is unclear why you think an `mpd_context_t` object would need to be provided, as no operation is performed on the decimal.

Comment: I assumed mpd_context_t is used for memory allocation. Thanks for providing the link to the source code!